# Create hostnames per IP on Debian

Tags: debian, dns, ip, hosts

I use a server with multiple IP addresses as a Squid proxy. Sadly every query to every IP address will expose the primary hostname of my webserver. So I added the following lines to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
213.2XX.2XX.XXX main.mars.customer.com  main
89.1XX.1XX.XX6  melle
89.1XX.131.X9   hannes
89.1XX.131.X0   vx
37.1XX.XXX.2X   vx2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I restarted the networking and rebooted the server, but every hostname query to every IP leads to `main.mars.customer.com`. I hope you can hint at what is exposing my hostname and how to change it.

I'm testing this by using hostname lookup services on the web.

Comment: *Sadly every query to every IP address will expose the primary hostname of my webserver.* -- why is that a problem? What *original* problem you think you can solve by "hiding" its hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a server/machine can only "ever" have a single hostname. that is it.
that means that `hostname` will always return the last hostname set for that machine.

each IP can have a different name associated with it, in as such as when somebody connects to it, or from it, and you ask "what is the name associated with this IP?" you can get the assigned name for the IP, or, when you query for a name, it will show the IP associated with that name.

here the ("default" Linux) commands to use: `getent hosts ip.ad.dr.ess` and `getent hosts nametoquery`

Right then there is the "web" for that you'll be needing to fix/change things in the reverse lookup tables, sometimes referred to as rDNS (Reverse DNS) and for that you'll need to talk to the relevant DNS administrator to put that in the DNS for you to change.

The IPs looks like they below a hosting provider, in which case you might just find (If I guess the correct provider) in the control panel the reverse lookup feature under the IPs section.

Comment: Yes you was right, thank you so much. I had to look inside the RDNS Settings not the interfaces.